# How to check numbers from a variable with an if in CMD (.bat file)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I know how to check time in command prompt, but I want to check if it's greater or equal to a number, I hope the example below is clear.

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('time /t') do (
    set t=%%a
)
set "dt=%t%"

if "%dt%" <= "12:00" ( 
    echo it is morning
    pause
)

if "%dt%" >= "12:00" ( 
    echo It is night
    pause
)
timeout /t 10 /nobreak>nul
```

I have tried 1200 and 12:00, is there a way to get the first 2 characters for a variable? I think this would be the easiest way.

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: @aschipfl To be honest I just jumped straight into this knowing it uses MS DOS, that's about all I know about it... haha, could you explain the difference between this and dos as it might help if I need to search in the future and to help me understand a bit more?  Thanks :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to select the first 2 characters of the variable `dt`, use

```
set "selection=%dt:~0,2%"
```

The `0` is the start position and `2` the length.

See `set /? |more` from the prompt for documentation

**BUT**

the `if` command has very specific requirements for comparison operators - and `>` and `<` are use to redirect files.

See `if /?` from the prompt for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this problem. I think this is the simplest one:

```
@echo off

set "t=%time::=%"
set /A "dt=t"

if %dt% leq 120000 (
    echo it is morning
    pause
)

if %dt% geq 190000 ( 
    echo It is night
    pause
)
```

The `set "t=%time::=%"` command get the `%time%` dynamic variable, that have a "HH:MM:SS.CC" format, and assign "HHMMSS.CC" to `t` variable. Then, `set /A "dt=t"` command get the number until first dot: "dt=HHMMSS". After that, just compare such a value *with no quotes*.